# ¿Como puedo validar que un INPUT TEXT no acepte caracteres especiales? ?!))$&.'!"@&

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función:

```
<input class="tf w-input" id="txtMsj" name="txtMsj" maxlength="256" placeholder="Identificación" type="text">
<input class="bn naranja w-button"  onclick="goto('frm')" value="Siguiente">

goto( doc ){
var txtMsj  document.getElementById("txtMsj").value;
}
```

Que me ayuda a obtener el texto de la pantalla pero no se como validar los caracteres especiales -> [?!))$&.'!"@&] con expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esta es la solución que implementé:

```
<input class="tf w-input" id="txtCurp" name="txtCurp" maxlength="256" onkeypress="return check(event)" placeholder="No. de CURP" type="text">
```

---

```
function check(e) {
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla == 8) {
        return true;
    }

    // Patrón de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros y letras
    patron = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

Comment: Excelente, iba a mostrar otra forma de hacerlo, pero si funciona genial!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacerlo directamente desde HTML, gracias a las nuevos atributos de HTML5:

> Este campo solo acepta letras minusculas:

```
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usern" pattern="[a-z]{1,15}">
```

> Esta expresion acepta letras, numeros y guiones con un rango de 1 a 15 caracteres:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,15}" name="user" placeholder="User">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}" name="" value="">
    <button type="button" name="button">click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solo quiero que sean letras y numeros, como quedaria la expresión?

Comment: Quedaría de la siguiente manera: pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}"

Comment: No me funciona, necesito forzosamente validar ese campo de texto con el puro Javascript

Answer (score 2):

### Solución rápida

Lo primero que debemos hacer es agregar una clase a nuestro **Input**
 para luego poder hacer referencia a ella desde una función en Jquery.

```
<div class="input-group">
   <label class="control-label">Precio:</label>
   <input type="number" id="precio" class="soloNumeros" min="1" />
</div>
```

El atributo **min** es para indicar que 1 será su valor mínimo, de
 esta manera no aceptará valores negativos.

El próximo paso será crear un script para evitar que el usuario pueda
 escribir símbolos en el input.

```
jQuery('.soloNumeros').keypress(function (tecla) {
  if (tecla.charCode < 48 || tecla.charCode > 57) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que el input solo cargue texto mayúsculas y minúsculas, números y no acepte caracteres especiales puedes agregar al input

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/,'')"
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style> 
input:invalid {border:red solid 3px;background-color:yellow;}
input:valid {background-color:white;}
input[required]{background-color:yellow;}
</style>
<body>
<p> Ejemplo poner una IP, ejemplo 10.10.10.10</p>
<p> El primero mostrara colores por input[required]</p>
<input type="text" onclick="goto()" required pattern="[0-9]{1,3}([.]?)[0-9]{1,3}\1[0-9]{1,3}\1[0-9]{1,3}">
<input type="text" onclick="goto()" pattern="[0-9]{1,3}([.]?)[0-9]{1,3}\1[0-9]{1,3}\1[0-9]{1,3}">
<script>
/*
Bucamos el que esta vacio y lo coloremos como tambien aplicamos focus 
*/
function goto(){
  const myTag = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (let i = 0; i < myTag.length; i++) {
   if (!myTag[i].value) { myTag[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; myTag[i].style.borderColor = "red"; myTag[i].focus(); return; } else { myTag[i].style.backgroundColor = "white"; myTag[i].style.borderColor = "black"; }
   }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Puede que otros usuarios más adelante lo vean y no comprendan cómo funciona. Recuerda que [es.so] _no es un repositorio de código_. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que te ofrece el type number pero no acepta el caracter "e"

charCode = 101 = e

`<input type="number" onkeypress="return event.charCode!=101">`

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/401913)

Answer (score -3):

//funcion para solo aceptar numeros y punto decimal

```
function SoloNumerosDecimales(e) {

var key;

if (window.event) // IE/Crome
{
    key = e.keyCode;
}
else if (e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
{
    key = e.which;
}

if (key < 46 || key > 57) {
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

//funcion para solo aceptar numeros

```
function SoloNumeros(e) {

var key;

if (window.event) // IE/Crome
{
    key = e.keyCode;
}
else if (e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
{
    key = e.which;
}

if (key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

//funcion para solo aceptar letras

```
function SoloLetras(letra) {

tecla = (document.all) ? letra.keyCode : letra.which;

//Tecla de retroceso para borrar, y espacio siempre la permite
if (tecla == 8 || tecla == 32) {
    return true;
}

// Patrón de entrada
patron = /[A-Za-z]/;
tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
return patron.test(tecla_final);

}
```

//funcion para solo aceptar letras y numeros

```
function SoloLetrasAndNumeros(letranum) {

tecla = (document.all) ? letranum.keyCode : letranum.which;

//Tecla de retroceso para borrar, y espacio siempre la permite
if (tecla == 8 || tecla == 32) {
    return true;
}

// Patrón de entrada
patron = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
return patron.test(tecla_final);

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración, al parecer esto no responde a la pregunta planteada, cuando respondas asegúrate de explicar siempre cómo tu propuesta soluciona el problema de OP, no solo pegar el código y también asegúrate de leer bien la pregunta para que así también tu respuesta sea adecuada. Te invito a leer [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y también a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), así también podrás ganar tu primera medalla. Saludos ;)